# Integrating $\int x \sin \sqrt x dx$ and substituting $u=\sqrt x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it wrong to substitute $u=\sqrt x$ when integrating?

Here's what I mean, I have to integrate: $\int x \sin \sqrt x dx$.

I defined $u=\sqrt x$ so it's: $$\int u^2\sin u du=2u{\cdot}\sin\left(u\right)+\left(2-{u}^{2}\right){\cdot}\cos\left(u\right)+{C}$$

But when placing back $\sqrt x$ I get a totally different result from the integration of the original expression: http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=xsinsqrtx

$$2{\cdot}\left(\cos\left(\sqrt{x}\right){\cdot}\left(6{\cdot}\sqrt{x}-{x}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)+\sin\left(\sqrt{x}\right){\cdot}\left(3x-6\right)\right)+{C}$$

Shouldn't both expressions be equal and why aren't they?

Comment: Your integral was supposed to be $$2\int u^3 \sin u\, du $$

Comment: @AaronMaroja why?

Comment: Depending on which interval you're working with, $u^2= x $. and $2 u\, du =dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u=\sqrt x,$ then $x=u^2,$ and so $$\frac{dx}{du}=2u.$$ Thus, we have $$\int x\sin\sqrt x\,dx=\int u^2\sin u\frac{dx}{du}\,du=2\int u^3\sin u\,du.$$ Upshot? Don't forget the chain rule!